# How to use MSDN documentation and Visual Studio to figure out what I need for "using" directives

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msdn

When I need a tool and find it on MSDN, I often find myself stuck on figuring out what `using` directive I need in order to use it. For example, I need `File.Exists(...)`, documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx), said to be in the `System.IO` namespace, but when I use it in my code I get a compiler error

> 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File(string, string, string)' is a
>   'method', which is not valid in the given context

This doesn't make sense because my context

```
if (!File.Exists(newFileNameAndPath))
     throw new Exception(string.Format("File with name {0} already exists in Assets folder. Not overwritten.", newFileName));
```

is straightforward and I have using `System.IO;` at the top. So what is the problem here?

I'm guessing that I actually need `using System.IO.something`, but I'm not sure how I can figure out what `something` is.

Comment: Both System.IO and System.Web.Mvc.Controller contains a class named File,

Comment: You can right click your File class(or any other class name you have in same conditions) and then go to resolve and you will see option for insert the correct Using or add the full path to the class

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this because `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` has method `File` and also `System.IO` has class `File`.

You can use fully qualified class name to prevent this resolving conflict:

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(newFileNameAndPath))
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to namespace your call to File.Exists

eg:

```
if (!IO.File.Exists(newFileNameAndPath))
```

Comment: Right answer. It is just an ambiguous method that exists on more than one namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly state which `File` class you want to use by using a [*using alias directive*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx):

```
using File = System.IO.File;

if (!File.Exists(newFileNameAndPath))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are two items with the name of `File`.

- [System.IO.File class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [System.Web.MVC.Controller.File method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx)

So if you had both `using` statements, you would get a conflict. The solution is to either fully qualify one of them (ex: `System.IO.File.Exists(newFileNameAndPath)`) or to use a [namespace alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
using IO = System.IO; //at the top of the file

...

if (!IO.File.Exists(newFileNameAndPath))
```